# Как поменять кодировку названия файла при его сохранении?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, opencv

Данная функция берет кадр с камеры и сохраняет его в виде изображения, название которого вводит пользователь. Всё работает с английским языком, но при вводе русского алфавита название файла будет состоять из непонятных символов. Как это исправить?

```
def capture_image(self):
    self.success, self.img = self.cap.read()
    file = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(parent=None, caption="Сохранение",
                                                 filter=".jpg")
    fileName = file[0]

    cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(f'{fileName}.jpg'), self.img)
```

Comment: `ok, data = cv2.imencode('JPG', self.img)` + [QFile](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfile.html) для записи

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю воспользоваться средствами Qt для записи файлов.

Примерный код:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QFile, QIODevice, QByteArray
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFileDialog, QApplication, QPushButton

import cv2
import numpy as np

from typing import List
import sys
import os

# Записывает данные в файл
def write_data(file_name: str, data: np.ndarray):
    file = QFile(file_name)
    ok = file.open(QIODevice.WriteOnly)

    if ok:
        bin_data = QByteArray(data.tobytes())
        file.write(bin_data)
    file.close()

# вызывает диалог сохранения
def save_as(image: Mat):
    file_name, _ = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(None, caption="Save As", filter="Jpeg(*.jpg)")
    if not file_name:
        return

    # fix up extension
    _, ext = os.path.splitext(file_name)
    if not ext:
        file_name += '.jpg'

    ok, data = imencode('.jpg', image)

    if ok:
        write_data(file_name, data)


def main(args: List[str]):
    app = QApplication(args)

    def call_save():
        image = np.zeros((128, 128), np.uint8)
        save_as(image)

    btn = QPushButton("Call Save")
    btn.clicked.connect(call_save)
    btn.show()
    return app.exec_()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
```